# package not found via setup.py but the same package already installed and available in import

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, setup.py

I have a module which have a requirement to CLD2 - lang. detector.

So I install this component in a stand alone way and now I could use it code without problem.

so this code `import cld2full` works fine and I could use this component.

However when running `python setyp.py develop` for my project I still get those error:

```
Processing dependencies for MyStuff==0.1
Searching for cld2full
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/cld2full/
Couldn't find index page for 'cld2full' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for cld2full
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('cld2full')
```

So what should I do make my setup procedure finished correctly?

Comment: Try to use pip manager. Try `pip install cld2full`

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies is MyStuff's `setup.py` are wrong. Package named `cld2full` does not exit on pypi.python.org. The module import name and package name can differ from each other.

You can confirm this by simply visiting this URL:

https://pypi.python.org/simple/cld2full/

Please refer the package by its correct name. Visit the documentation of the package to get its name on pypi.python.org.

Comment: this package not available via pip install procedure. It's C component compiled to *.so files

Comment: You need to package it a to proper Python package if you want to declare it as setup.py dependency.

Comment: If the author of the code has not done packaging here are some starting points for creating a Python package https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing/